# Simplify Expressions in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I wanted to ask how I can simplify expressions like:

```
1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0
= 3+a*5
```

And especially how can I separate such expressions in lists.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually kind of fun in Prolog, because you don't need to do anything too magical to make it work.

```
?- X-Y = 1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0.
X = 1+2+a*5+0/b,
Y = c*0.
```

So you could start by doing something like this:

```
simplify(C, C) :- atom(C) ; number(C).
simplify(X+Y, X1+Y1) :- simplify(X, X1), simplify(Y, Y1).
simplify(X*Y, X1*Y1) :- simplify(X, X1), simplify(Y, Y1).
simplify(X/Y, X1/Y1) :- simplify(X, X1), simplify(Y, Y1).
simplify(X-Y, X1-Y1) :- simplify(X, X1), simplify(Y, Y1).
```

This is an identity transform: it doesn't do anything.

```
?- simplify(1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0, Result).
Result = 1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0.
```

Now you can add rules for specific cases:

```
simplify(X*0, 0).
simplify(0*X, 0).
```

Now you get multiple results:

```
?- simplify(1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0, Result).
Result = 1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0 ;
Result = 1+2+a*5+0/b-0 ;
```

You could add a rule for constant folding:

```
simplify(X+Y, C)     :- number(X), number(Y), C is X+Y.
```

You know, just have fun with it.

Lists aren't really any easier to work with, but you can make them using the "univ" operator: `=..`:

```
?- 1+2+a*5+0/b-c*0 =.. R.
R = [-, 1+2+a*5+0/b, c*0].
```

Comment: Hey, I have a problem. My code is : simplify(C, C) :- atom(C) ; integer(C).
simplify(X+Y, X1+Y1) :- simplify(X, X1), simplify(Y, Y1).

simplify(X+X, 2*X) :- atom(X). I wanted to calculate b + a + a which should give me b + 2*a, but it only says b + a + a.

Comment: `b + a + a` is equivalent to `(b + a) + a`, which will not match `X + X`. Try your example with explicit parentheses the way you want them: `b + (a + a)`.

Comment: Yes but isn't there any possibility to do this? So b+a+a AND a+a+b would give me b + 2*a and 2*a + b? I want to simplify expressions and it would be nice if that would be possible.

Comment: @zer0kai Sure, you can match that case explicitly, or you could look for runs of the same operator and turn them into some kind of list and sort it or something. Try a few things, it should be possible.

Comment: My problem is also I want to output the best simplified expression but instead my code give me all possibilities to simplify an expression. Like:   a * a = a * a and a * a = 2 * a.

Comment: @zer0kai You're going to have to come up with a formal notion of "best" and teach it to Prolog. I would probably make it an ordering and then use `setof/3` to find all the simplifications and choose the best one. I would not expect this to be obvious; which is "simpler" of `a+a` and `2*a`? What about `a*a` and `a^2`? You have to make these hair-splitting decisions and then code them up.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to simplify expressions in Prolog using unification, but this sometimes leads to unexpected results. In this example, two different variables in an expression are unified when "matching" a pattern, even if they were intended to be distinct:

```
:- initialization(main).

simplify(A+A,2*A).

main :-
    simplify(A+B,C),
    writeln(C).
```

In this case, `simplify(A+B,C)` would unify `A` with `B`.

To solve this problem, I use [`subsumes_term/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subsumes_term/2) to match a pattern without unifying the variables in an expression. `subsumes_term(A+A,Input)` will not match `A+B` unless `A` is already unified with `B`:

```
simplify(Input,2*A) :-
    subsumes_term(A+A,Input).
```

This `subsumes_term/2` predicate is often useful for metaprogramming: I used it to write a [Prolog-to-Minizinc compiler](https://github.com/jarble/prolog-to-minizinc).