# Prolog - Simplifying rules or statements

Tags: prolog, simplify

I've been looking at ways in which Prolog can automatically simplify statements. This is because I am planning to receive Prolog statements from an external source and won't necessarily be manually created.

I've seen from questions such as this: [Simplify Expressions in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278310/simplify-expressions-in-prolog) that mathematical expressions can be simplified and Prolog handles that quite well.

However I'm wondering if it can do something else. Consider the following:

```
and(X, Y) :- X, Y.

simplified(X) :- X.

?- simplified(and(5 > 3, 5 > 3)).
```

In this example I have a simple and statement that takes in two values. In this example though the two statements are the same and so are pointless. I'm wondering if Prolog has a way or if there is a way of detecting this to remove it so that it only evaluates the statement once instead of twice thus simplifying the call that it needs to do.

I hope that makes sense and I realise that the question is probably a bit of a weird one but there is a specific reason I have for wanting to know this and plan to do something more complicated later on if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `==/2` which succeeds of the terms are identical. For example, these succeed: `(5 > 3) == (5 > 3)`, and `(X + Y) == (X + Y).`. But this fails: `(X + Y) == (Z + W)`. So you could have, `and(X, Y) :- X == Y, X.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a predicate that simplifies the expression.

For example we know that `and(X, Y)` where `X` and `Y` are equal, is equal to `X` itself.

So we can write a predicate like:

```
simplify(and(X1, X2), Y1) :-
    simplify(X1, Y1),
    simplify(X2, Y2),
    Y1 == Y2,
    !.
simplify(or(X1, X2), Y1) :-
    simplify(X1, Y2),
    simplify(X2, Y1),
    Y1 == Y2,
    !.
simplify(not(not(X)), Y) :-
    simplify(X, Y),
    !.
 simplify(X, X).
```

Here we thus define three rules: `and(X, X)` is equal to `X`, `or(X, X)` is equal to `X`, and `not(not(X))` is equal to `X`. We make extra calls since it is possible to have `not(not(and(3 < 5, 3 < 5)))`, so we still want to simplify the *inner* value. We then thus obtain:

```
?- simplify(not(not(and(3 < 5, 3 < 5))), X).
X =  (3<5).
```

Other items can be added (before the last clause in the previous code fragment) like:

```
simplify(X > Y, S) :-
    simplify(Y < X, S).

simplify(X >= Y, S) :-
    simplify(Y =< X, S).
```

Such that for example `and(5 < 3, 3 > 5)` is simplified to `3 < 5` as well.